Test explorer missing single test iterations when path to data is changed
When i use this combination for reaching to .csv file with test data,
`
[PictCsvDataSource(
    typeof(ActivePartDataRow),
    "..\\..\\UITestsResources\\AngieIntegration\\ActivePart\\ActivePart\\ActivePart.Mapping.WithoutCoils.Runner.csv",
    "..\\..\\UITestsResources\\AngieIntegration\\ActivePart\\ActivePart\\ActivePart.Mapping.WithoutCoils.pict.csv")]`

notice that TestExplorer creates "subentries" with subentries
But when i change paths to this:
[PictCsvDataSource(
    typeof(ActivePartDataRow),
    "AngieIntegration\\ActivePart\\ActivePart\\ActivePart.Mapping.WithoutCoils.Runner.csv",
    "AngieIntegration\\ActivePart\\ActivePart\\ActivePart.Mapping.WithoutCoils.pict.csv")]

Then Test Explorer loses those "subentries" without subentries
Why is that?
PictCsvDataSource derives from Attribute and implements ITestDataSource
 public IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(MethodInfo methodInfo)
 {
     var runnerData = new TestCaseReader<RunnerData>()
         .GetRows(RunnerCsvFileLocation, _csvDelimiter);

     for (var i = 0; i < runnerData.Count; i++)
     {
         runnerData[i].DataRow = i;
     }

     var pictData = new TestCaseReader()
         .GetRows(_dataRowTargetType, PictCsvFileLocation, _pictDelimiter);

     if (runnerData.Count != pictData.Count)
     {
         throw new InvalidOperationException(
             $"Number of {nameof(runnerData)} and {nameof(pictData)} data rows has to be equal! Invalid test case!");
     }

     for (var i = 0; i < runnerData.Count; i++)
     {
         if (_rangeTargetType != null)
         {
             yield return new[] { runnerData[i], pictData[i], new TestCaseReader().GetRows(_rangeTargetType, RangeCsvFileLocation, _pictDelimiter)[0] };
         }
         else
         {
             yield return new[] { runnerData[i], pictData[i] };
         }
     }
 }

GetRows()
public List<object> GetRows(Type targetType, string fileFullName, string delimiter)
{
    var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileFullName);
    using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(
            streamReader,
            new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Delimiter = delimiter
            }))
    {
        return csvReader.GetRecords(targetType).ToList();
    }
}

